# percentage two numbers and show final result in another td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that consists of tr and tds and I show the percentage of sold ticket in third  td. the problem of this code is it generate a zero after each percentage, i think it is for br tag . 
what should i do ?
here is my snippet :

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this) 
    .html()
    .trim() 
    .split(/\D+/); 
  $('span.result', $this).html(
    $('td:nth-child(1)', $this) 
    .html() 
    .trim() 
    .split(/\D+/) 
    .map(function(v, i) {
      return Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0);
    })
    .join('<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avalable</th>
      <!--available-->
      <th>Sold</th>
      <!--used-->
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>30 <br/></td>
    <!--available-->
    <td>4 <br/></td>
    <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>20 <br/> 20 <br/></td>
    <!--available-->
    <td>6 <br/> 5 <br/></td>
    <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `html()`, so there's an extra line added to the output which then gets evaluated in the calculation. Use `text()` instead:

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    td1Value = $this.find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim().split(/\D+/),
    td2Value = $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim().split(/\D+/);

  $this.find('span.result').html(td1Value.map(function(v, i) {
    return Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0) + '%';
  }).join('<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avalable</th>
      <th>Sold</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>30 <br/></td>
    <td>4 <br/></td>
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20 <br/> 20 <br/></td>
    <td>6 <br/> 5 <br/></td>
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I tidied up your logic a little too.

Comment: thank you so much. excuse me i have a question. how can i add a % in result ?

Comment: You can append it to the returned value. I updated the answer to show you where exactly

Comment: @aynaz At this point you received a solution without any initial work (see your previous question) and received a fix for the issues you had with that solution. As you said, you are new to this, I think it might be time now for you to try to understand the code you are working with.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry i eddited your answer Mistakenly instead of my question. i have a problem with the code you wrote . can you chek your edited question that i have eddited? the zero again repeats

Answer (score 0):

you are looping on content  inside  for first 2  you have numbers but for 3rd td, if you will debug you can see loop is doing one extra iteration.

Just put below line in map function before return statement :

console.log('>>>', td2Value[i],v,i);